# ghci: keep defined values in scope after module reload

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am wondering if it is possible to keep assigned values in ghci when a module is reloaded?

For example i assign a value in ghci:

```
ghci> let x = 1
```

or

```
ghci> x <- getLine
```

After entering `:r` to reload an existing module `x` is not in scope anymore. Is it generally possible to keep the assignment available, like for example in the Python interpreter? (this is really convenient...)

Even tho that actually each line in ghci represents a function that is (monadically) *bound* to the next one I am still wondering if maintaining that state is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I persist the environment between GHCi reloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428153/how-can-i-persist-the-environment-between-ghci-reloads)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way of doing this.

The trouble is that you could have some variable bound to a value of a certain type, edit the source to remove that type, and hit reload. Now you have a variable of a type that no longer exists.

Still, you would think it shouldn't be too hard to detect that, and discard just the variables that don't make sense any more. (The really fun part is presumably when a type still exists but has a different number of fields now, or something like that...)

Comment: I don't think ghci can do it, but it's perfectly possible to make an interactive Haskell that retains the bindings. Also, there is not really any need for a :reload command.

Comment: Hum that depends how the variable is bound to a name space. I just recently started to use the python interactive interpreter and found this feature quite convenient. If you bind a variable `x = 3` lets say in the module `test` then this variable is in scope via `test.x`. If you delete `x` in `test` and reload the module `test.x` is gone whereas for example a previously defined variable `x` at top-level is still in scope.